# HTML5 site enter full screen mode in silk browser or hide the address bar in silk browser after loading the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amazon-silk

1. when the page is loaded, it should enter in full screen mode. How do
   I force the browser to enter in full screen mode? or hide the
   address    bar?
2. How do I detect silk browser user agent in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question 2 (How do I detect silk browser user agent in jquery)

Basic Silk identification

```
if (/\bSilk\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    alert("Silk detected!");
}
```

To detect mobile/desktop preference

```
var match = /\bSilk\/(.*\bMobile Safari\b)?/.exec(navigator.userAgent);
if (match) {
    alert("Detected Silk in mode "+(match[1] ? "Mobile" : "Default (desktop)"));
}
```